# Show the configured DNS server on a Unifi device from the CLI

Tags: networking

When I am connected to a Unifi network device via the shell (SSH/Putty/Unifi admin shell), how do I show the current DNS server that is configured?

Answer (score 0):

Type the following and press Enter:

> cat /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: first type ```cli```